# Django smpt email backend slowing down performance

Tags: django, django-admin, django-signals, django-email

I'm developing/serving currently locally.

I'm using django-admin for internal users to add items.

I add in my signal code. My signal is post_save and it's purpose is to send an email to a user for approval. I test my signal using console.EmailBackend

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

I add a new item, there is no performance impact to the web browser. My models item page reloads quickly.

I update my EMAIL_BACKEND too use smpt details

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

I add a new item, the performance impact is massive, my web browser now takes 15-30 seconds to to reload the items page after adding.

Any thoughts around why the performance is so terrible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real e-mail send is slow in nature.

I recommend recommend sending an email using asynchronous Queue task. For example Celery is good library for [asynchronous Queue task](https://github.com/celery/celery#whats-a-task-queue).

Comment: thats what i was have thinking so the signal is not async... hmmmm

Comment: do you happen to have any examples?

Comment: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13567160/django-best-way-to-send-email-in-background) @RachOdwyer

Comment: thank you, as a stop gap for POC I'm going to take the easy way out and use django-celery-email however once in a development environment running celery, rabbit and will look to use the above

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on running your application on AWS or similar, consider using an email sending service (such as AWS's SES). It will let you set up sender verification (DKIM/SPF) and it'll be a low-latency API call rather than the slow SMTP interaction. If you're planning on using AWS, there is already a lib, [django-ses](https://github.com/django-ses/django-ses), which you can configure and begin using immediately.

If you want to continue sending the emails yourself, set up an asynchronous task queue and worker, using [celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#using-celery-with-django) or [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This deferral will let your web worker continue serving requests, while the worker finishes the slow process of sending.

If you want a really speedy setup, you could combine the two above approaches, deferring email sending to an asynchronous worker which then hits an email-as-a-service API. Your web worker will be snappy, and your async worker won't be blocked talking to an SMTP server for 10-15 seconds!

Comment: thank you, as a stop gap for POC I'm going to take the easy way out and use django-celery-email however once in a development environment running celery, rabbit and will look to use the above