# Speeding up chat bot replies in django python

Tags: python, django, celery, chatbot

I have made a chat bot in django python which listens via Http requests. Certain chat channels, such as slack, require an immediate 200OK http response from the server. Hence I register a celery task (into a queue) to return http 200OK instantly and let the reply be processed in background.

It is taking 3-4 seconds in production (SQS based) for the bot's reply to be received by the end user. Through logs I have found out that the delay is in the task to reach the celery worker.

I want to make my chat bot's replies to come really fast when a user types in a message and am looking for a faster alternative to celery for this specific use case. Thank you!

Note that I do not want to use slack's [RTM api](https://api.slack.com/rtm) because I do not intend to make my bot slack specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using multi threading as explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420699/multithreading-for-python-django) answer, although I am not so sure about scalability of this solution as of yet.