# How multiple invocation of same view is handled in django?

Tags: django, django-models

There is a view in the Django, for the submit button I say it: printSO

Now, the request is comming to view from two different browsers from the same machine, then how django is handling this?

**Question:**

Does it use any threading concept to invoke two different executions in parallel?

Considering the below scenario: pseudo code:

```
def results(request, emp_id):
    # if  emp_id exists in the database, then delete it.
    # send response with message "deleted"
```

Do we need to have any synchronization  mechanism in the above code?

Comment: They're two different clients.. The development server is single threaded and hence, not suited for this. When you use a different server (ie. Apache), <I think> several instances of the python interpreter are run (I'm absolutely not sure about the later, sorry)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can Django do multi-thread works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-django-do-multi-thread-works)

Answer (score 0):

The Django development server is single threaded and not suited for processing more than a request at the same time (I believe this is due to the GIL lock).
However, when combined with a different server , such as Apache, the later handles multithreading (in C). Here is some info (modwsgi) :

[Modwsgi](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ProcessesAndThreading)

To your final question: no, you don't need to sync anything in most cases

> Since Django 1.4 the development server has been multi-threaded
> [See here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#development-server-multithreading)
>
> though it is still not a
> production level webserver

Comment: Since Django 1.4 the development server has been multi-threaded https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#development-server-multithreading though it is still not a production level webserver.