# How can i trigger a Python script in background from HTML tag button, in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, performance, django-rest-framework

Please, how can i run a python script from my Django platform?
I have a custom html page and i have a button tag (`<button></button>`) from which i would like to trigger the python code I've written on PDF's (wonderful parser).

Actually, if the user of this app clicks on this **parse it** button, it triggers my python script stored in my static folder, and prints back the extracted texts and images in the table below:

[image: sample front end view]

I greatly need your helps and possible ideas.

Thanks before !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945052/simple-approach-to-launching-background-task-in-django

Comment: You can use any background task management system you want, for this simple use additional thread would suffice, use RQ for a bit more sophisticated approach or Celery for full robust solution

Comment: But you're not actually asking for a background task. You want it to run synchronously. Just call it from your view.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the script to a view and call it like this. i.e in the `views.py` file

`<a href = {% url 'wonderful_script' %} class="btn btn-primary" role="button"> Wonderful Parser </a>`

Make sure you bind that view to an url in urls.py too.

`url(r'^parse/$', wonderful_script, name='wonderful_script')`

Here the `wonderful_script` in the middle is the view that you defined in the views.py. It must have all the code of your parser script.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a view for page that you want to add a button to it you can do something like this

```
{# test.html #}
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" name="button_name" value="run_script">
</form>
```

and your view:

```
def test_view(requests):
    if(request.method == 'POST' && request.POST['button_name'] == 'run_script'):
        # do what you want when button clicked
    else:
        # other things in your views if you have
    return render(requests, 'test.html', {})
```