# how to create trigger which execute specific function at 12:00 AM in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to create a Trigger or schedule to execute a specific function at 12:01 AM(midnight) in Django.

I expect like :

```
def job:
    print("hello")

 // run this function every 12:01 AM on specific interval(start_date,end_date)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple approach to launching background task in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21945052/simple-approach-to-launching-background-task-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making that function into a [django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it via crontab.

```sh
1 0 * * * python /path/to/project/manage.py job
```