# The best way for doing something in background Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, background

I need my Django app processing some functions in background periodically. What is the best way for making such functions? And how can I call some functions when server starts? For example, functions of pre-init.

Comment: this should help solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788049/11891228

Comment: Have you done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For periodical jobs, you can try [Django RQ Scheduler](https://pypi.org/project/django-rq-scheduler/).

As for running functions at runtime, you can place the code in any models.py file or in apps.py like following

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class FooConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'foo'

    def ready(self):
        # import here and do logic
```