# how can I use django channels for background tasks

Tags: django, asynchronous, django-channels

I am seeing that people are using **celery** in **Django** for background tasks.

But i want to know that is there any way to do **background tasks** in Django with **django-channels**

so please tell me how do I do it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your project, I haven't used django-channels. Go through the comments on this page

[Can Django do multi-thread works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-django-do-multi-thread-works)

Also check those [packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/workers-queues-tasks/)