# Handle multiple post request in Django (Python)

Tags: python, django, multithreading, python-asyncio

Have created one web application using Django and Python. I am passing some inputs to the pickle model and getting prediction value(on the web page) based on the input data passed to the ML model present in pickle format.

I want the web to handle multiple requests parallelly using Django. i.e if multiple users are passing inputs on the web page and wanting prediction values at the same time. How to manage the above scenario.

Please provide me high-level scenarios like how to handle this case. You can provide links, videos e.t.c.

Django Version: 3.0.2
Python Version: 3.7

Answer (score 1):

There is a multithreading issue and a related question.

> [Can Django do multi-thread works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-django-do-multi-thread-works)