# Multithreading in Django

Tags: python, django, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm working on a Django project, in which I will need the use of multithreading and multiprocessing concepts (Send and receive data from other servers such as PACS server/ I/O Threads... ).

The question I have is Django capable of applying multithreading /multiprocessing?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far the most popular tool in the Django world for doing this is [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html) [Here is a good intro tutorial](https://testdriven.io/guides/django-celery/)

There are some more lightweight packages like [Dramatiq](https://dramatiq.io/) and [django-db-queue](https://github.com/dabapps/django-db-queue), which are intended for use cases where the configuration associated with Celery could be considered overkill.

You could, of course, '*roll-your-own*' with the threading module, as sketched out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-you-perform-multi-threaded-tasks-within-django)

Comment: Thank you, going to learn celery now

Comment: I have seen in some examples that, celery is used with rabitMQ and redis, we can use celery without them right? @pj-simpo

Comment: @OussamaEddahri No, celery will require a message queue and a backend: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/backends-and-brokers/index.html. Maybe django-db-queue is more suited to your requirements?