# Execute several scripts at the same time in the background

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a page where the user selects a Python script, and then this script executes.
My issue is that some scripts take a while to execute (up to 30m) so I'd like to run them in the background while the user can still navigate on the website.

I tried to use Celery but as I'm on Windows I couldn't do better than using `--pool=solo` which, while allowing the user to do something else, can only do so for one user at a time.

I also saw [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17601698/can-you-perform-multi-threaded-tasks-within-django) while searching for a solution, but didn't manage to really understand how it worked nor how to implement it, as well as determine if it was really answering my problem...

So here is my question : how can I have multiple thread/multiple processes on Celery **while on Windows** ? Or if there's another way, how can I execute several tasks simultaneously in the background ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you identified whether your slow scripts belong to CPU-bound tasks or I/O bound tasks?

if they're I/O bound, you can use eventlet and gevent based on Strategy 1 in [the blog from distributedpython.com](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/)

but if they're CPU bound, you may have to think of using the ways like a dedicated Celery windows box (or windows Docker container) to workaround Celery billiard issue on Windows by setting the environment variable (`FORKED_BY_MULTIPROCESSING=1`) based on Strategy 2 in [the blog from distributedpython.com](https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/08/21/celery-4-windows/)

Comment: Using eventlet worked fine with me, thank you so much !